# ¿Reemplaza "Async/Await" a "Backgroundworker"?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net

Saludos a todos:

Conozco de hace tiempo el `BackgroundWorker` y aunque fue complicado llegar a entender su funcionamiento, lo uso de forma satisfactoria pese a las limitaciones que plantea. 
Estoy dando mis primeros pasos con `Async/Await` y entiendo cuales son sus puntos fuertes más evidentes frente a `Backgroundworker` pero se me plantea la duda de si `Async/Await` ha venido a sustituir `BackgroundWorker` o viene a complementarse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si bien podría verse como que `async/await` sustituye el uso que se le da al `BackgroundWorker`, no creo que sea el caso. es más, bajo mi punto de vista no sólo son cosas diferentes si no que tienen propósitos diferentes.

Es posible que en casos concretos, puedas hacer uso de `async` o de `BackgroundWorker` indistintamente, pero eso no los convierte necesariamente en equivalentes.

### BackgroundWorker

El propósito del `BackgroundWorker` es definir una tarea que se ejecutará en segundo plano en otro hilo de ejecución. Básicamente, el problema al que pretende dar solución el `BackgroundWorker` es el de ejecutar una única tarea pesada en segundo plano para evitar que la interfaz se quede en un estado *no responsivo*.

Un ejemplo clásico sería por ejemplo una sincronización de datos. Un cliente tiene unos datos locales que periódicamente realiza una sincronización completa a la parte de servidor. Ese caso de uso encaja con el planteamiento y funcionamiento del `BackgroundWorker`.

### async/await

El objetivo de usar `async/await` es diferente. Se pretende ejecutar una lógica en diferido, sin parar la ejecución del programa (o al contrario para el caso de `await`). No es necesariamente una tarea pesada que relegar a un segundo plano, sino simplemente una petición/método que invocamos de forma asíncrona para no detener la ejecución del proceso.

Un caso típico del uso de `async/await` se podría ver al enviar un formulario cliente a un servidor o al iniciar sesión con un proveedor externo (como LDAP por ejemplo), dependiendo de tus necesidades, podrías no querer que se parase la ejecución (haciendo uso de `async`) y en otros en los que si necesitas esperar la respuesta antes de continuar (haciendo uso del `await`).

Es improtante remarcar que `async/await` **no** utilizan otros hilos de ejecución.

Puede ser de mucha ayuda revisar el artículo de la [MSDN - Programación asíncrona con Async y Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh191443.aspx).

En ese enlace, hay un párrafo relevante sobre que operaciones están desaconsejadas para el background worker:

> The async-based approach to asynchronous programming is preferable to
>   existing approaches in almost every case. In particular, this approach
>   is better than BackgroundWorker for IO-bound operations because the
>   code is simpler and you don't have to guard against race conditions.
>   In combination with Task.Run, async programming is better than
>   BackgroundWorker for CPU-bound operations because async programming
>   separates the coordination details of running your code from the work
>   that Task.Run transfers to the threadpool.

Traducción casera:

> Este enfoque basado en `async` para la programación asíncrona es
>   preferible a los enfoques existentes en casi cualquier caso. En
>   particular, este enfoque es mejor que `BackgroundWorker` para las
>   operaciones asociadas a `E/S` por que el código es más simple y no
>   necesitas protegerte contra desincronización de hilos. En combinación
>   con `[Task.Run][2]`, la programación asíncrona es mejor que
>   `BackgroundWorker`para operaciones vinculadas a la CPU por que separa
>   los detalles de coordinación entre la ejcución del código y el trabajo
>   que realiza la tarea al transferirse desde el `threadpool`

He dejado la versión original por que me he tomado ciertas libertades con la traducción.

Pese a todo, sigo creyendo que `BackgroundWorker` sigue teniendo su caso de uso, la diferencia está en que hoy en día los casos de uso en los que `BackgroundWorker` encaja mejor son menos, ya que cada vez nos centramos en *atomizar* todo lo posible las operaciones en *microllamadas* y carecemos de operaciones pesadas (por norma general) que ejecutar en segundo plano.

Salvo esos casos concretos, considero que la recomendación actual que [en el primer epígrafe de éste artículo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/async) es más que correcto para el paradigma de programación del que se suele hacer uso en estos tiempos.

> El modelo es bastante simple en la mayoría de los casos: Para el
>   código vinculado a `E/S`, realizas una operación `await` que devuelve
>   un `Task` o `Task<T>` del de un método asíncrono.
>
> Para el código asociado a CPU, realizas una oepración `await` que se
>   empieza en un hilo en segundo plano con el método `Task.Run`.
>
> La directiva `await` es donde ocurre la magia, porque delega el
>   control al invocador del método que ejecuta el `await`. Esto es lo que
>   en última instancia permita a la IU ser responsiva, o a un servicio
>   ser elástico.

Comment: Gran explicación de la diferencia entre ambas clases. +1

Comment: ¡Gran respuesta!

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo que te has tomado en responder. La verdad es que la intuición me decía que los tiros iban por ahi. Tengo pequeños procesos que ejecutan largos y pesados trabajos que me costaba imaginar escribirlos sin emplear un hilo para ello.

Answer (score 3):

En principio no son exactamente iguales, aunque todo lo que es posible hacer con `BackgroundWorker` se puede implementar de igual manera con `Async/await`. En cuanto a lo de si vienen a sustituir a `BackgroundWorker` lo cierto es que de momento microsoft no lo ha marcado como obsoleto, pero en [esta pagina](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/jj152938.aspx) se especifica que para nuevos desarrollos se recomienda el uso del *Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)*:

> Asynchronous Programming Model (APM):
>   Describe el modelo antiguo que utiliza la interfaz IAsyncResult para proporcionar un comportamiento asíncrono. Este modelo ya no se recomienda para nuevos desarrollos.
>
> Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP): 
>   Describe el modelo antiguo basado en eventos para proporcionar comportamiento asíncrono. Este modelo ya no se recomienda para nuevos desarrollos.
>
> Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP):
>   Describe el nuevo patrón asíncrono basado en el espacio de nombres System.Threading.Tasks. Este modelo es el enfoque recomendado para la programación asíncrona en .NET Framework 4 y versiones posteriores.

Resumiendo, yo no me preocuparía de modificar el código que ya tengas utilizando `BackgroundWorker`, pero para cualquier desarrollo nuevo usa `Task` con `Async/await`

Comment: Me parece muy clarificador el enlace que vinculas sobre _APP_ y me parece muy interesante para entender los modelos asíncronos de trabajo. Por otro lado, no estoy seguro de que _de momento microsoft no lo ha marcado como obsoleto_ no estoy seguro de que esto sea cierto, ¿Puedes añadir una fuente con la info? Hasta donde tengo conocimiento, tenía entendido que se había marcado como obsoleto su uso para operaciones de E/S y no la clase en sí

Comment: @frikinside bueno, basicamente me baso en la [documentacion del `BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) en la que en ningun lugar se especifica que sea una clase obsoleta. Pero ahora que lo comentas, si me suena que el uso para operaciones de E/S se habia marcado como obsoleto. A ver si encuentro algun sitio donde se especifique.

Comment: En el enlace de la documentación no veo ningún indicativo de que su uso esté marcado como obsoleto (pero igual soy yo que se me ha pasado) podrías indicarme en que sección para poder revisarlo? Por otro lado, yo hubiera dicho que en este [enlace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh191443.aspx) cuando recomendaba los usos de `Task.Run`, `await` y demás, se hacía mención a no usar al `BackgroundWorker` para operaciones de `E/S` pero ahora no soy capaz de encontrarlo, es como si hubieran cambiado `BackgroundWorker` por `background` únicamente.

Comment: @frikinside no me leiste bien. Lo que digo es precisamente que en la documentación **no** se especifica en ningun lugar que la clase sea obsoleta :)

Comment: si esque... no hay nada como leer, por cierto ya encontré el fragmento donde habla del BackgroundWorker y su uso desaconsejado: _In particular, this approach is better than BackgroundWorker for IO-bound operations_

Comment: Gracias por la información, es muy educativa.